# Conditions for $e^X$ to be an orthogonal matrix

Tags: matrices, orthogonal-matrices, matrix-exponential, skew-symmetric-matrices

If $X$ is a skew-symmetric matrix, its exponential $e^X$ is orthogonal. Does the converse implication hold?